# Why do the cops shoot at Blade without provocation

Tags: blade

After Blade invades the coroner, why are the cops so ready to shoot at him and even more so with a machine gun and in force. They never say stop or I'll shoot.

Is this just the movie makers need more gunfire and a reason for him to run away with doctor? Or is there a cannon reason for it?

I know they do say that the cops are totally bought by vampires and that there is that cop that is a vampire hanger on but the total corruption is inconsistent with taking the badly burnt vampire to the morgue- why  didn't they drop him on the street so he can eat off homeless people or passers-by.

Comment: It's set in America, remember? Cops shoot black people. Blade is black. Cops shoot Blade.

Comment: Then they're *way* off protocol. For one, he's holding a samurai sword, not [a tiny screwdriver](https://www.google.com/search?q=dallas+shooting+screwdriver&tbm=nws).

Comment: BTW, it could be argued that the *security guards* displayed a bit more common sense: at least Karen was on the floor and out of harms way when they shot Blade. But the cops kept shooting willy-nilly *at her direction* as he was carrying her. Can't think of a reason other than 'corrupt', 'shoddy script device' or 'worst\most racist cops ever'.

Answer (score 2):

They work for the vampires in the same capacity as police-officer Gideon:

```
            KAREN
    But he's a policeman --

            BLADE
    He's a familiar. A human who works for 
    the vampires. See this mark?

Blade pushes aside Gideon's hair, revealing a tiny, cryptic symbol
tattooed into the man's scalp.
```

Blade even explains this point quite succinctly when he's introducing the female protagonist to the underworld he inhabits:

```
            KAREN
    I can go to the police. I have blood 
    samples back at the hospital. I can 
    show them. 

            BLADE
    Do it. You'll be dead before you can 
    file the complaint.

            KAREN
    That's ridiculous! No one's that 
    powerful. 

Whistler sighs. He doesn't suffer fools gladly.

            WHISTLER 
    You're talking about a brotherhood 
    that predates the Catholic Church by 
    thousands of years. Their survival 
    depends on their ability to blend in. 
    Chances are, you've encountered them 
    and not even known it. On the subway, 
    in a bar --
```

So basically, they were either familiars like Gideon or their boss was. It's not really important because policemen follow the orders they're given.

Comment: Are you saying beat cops wait for orders?  They see a guy invading the coroners and they immediately call in despatch-really??